# AngularJS ngRoute - Rendering template along with Angular Controller the $routeProvider is pointing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mvvm, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

I'm rendering template using `ngRoute` - `$routeProvider` and I'm trying to render respective controller along with the template. `$routeProvider` is pointing to that controller and so it gives me an error **controller is undefined** because I think the App is trying to call the controller before it receives the template.

The `templateCtr` definition is in the separate JS file.

**app.js**

```
...
$routeProvider
    .when('/template', {
        templateUrl: '/template.html',
        controller: 'templateCtr'
    })
;
```

**template.html**

```
...
<script src="templateCtr.js"></script>
```

**templateCtr.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp'); //Getting module reference
myApp.controller('templateCtr', ['$scope', function($scope){
    ...
}]);
```

I also came across `resolve` property using which can load data to be used in controller before view is generated but for that too controller has to present in the memory.

Someone please point me to the correct direction. Thanks!

Comment: The `templateCtr.js` should be referenced on your index page not the template (template.html) itself.

Comment: @shammelburg I know that and that's the way it works but I do not want that as I do not want to load that controller unless it's required.

Comment: so you want to load the view and not the controller? at what point would you want the controller?

Comment: @shammelburg I want load the controller along with the view.